# Configuring rack-test to start the server indirectly

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack-test

Here is my rack application:

```
class MainAppLogic
    def initialize
        Rack::Server.start(:app =>Server, :server => "WEBrick", :Port => "8080")
    end
end

class Server
    def self.call(env)
        return [200, {},["Hello, World"]]
    end
end
```

When actually run, it behaves as it should and returns "Hello World" to all requests. I'm having trouble convincing rack-test to work with it. Here are my tests:

```
require "rspec"
require "rack/test"
require "app"

# Rspec config source: https://github.com/shiroyasha/sinatra_rspec    
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

describe MainAppLogic do

    # App method source: https://github.com/shiroyasha/sinatra_rspec
    def app
        MainAppLogic.new
    end

    it "starts a server when initialized" do
        get "/", {}, "SERVER_PORT" => "8080"
        last_response.body.should be != nil
    end
end
```

When I test this, it fails complaining that `MainAppLogic` is not a rack server, specifically, that it doesn't respond to `MainAppLogic.call`. How can I let it know to ignore that `MainAppLogic` isn't a rack server and just place a request to `localhost:8080`, because there server has started?

Comment: This advice doesn't help you with your problem, but you might want to know that standard Ruby indentation is two spaces.  It's not bad to indent four--Ruby itself doesn't care--it just looks a little odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: why the custom class to run the app? You can use the `rackup` tool, which is the de-facto standard for running Rack apps. Some more details on it [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/(tutorial)-rackup-howto).

Your app code then becomes:

```
class App
  def call(env)
    return [200, {}, ['Hello, World!']]
  end
end
```

and with the `config.ru`

```
require_relative 'app'

run App.new
```

you can start the app by running `rackup` in your project's directory.

As for the error, the message is pretty clear. `rack-test` expects, that the return value of `app` method would be an instance of a rack app (an object that responds to `call` method). Take a look what happens in `rack-test` internals (it's pretty easy to follow, as a tip—focus on these in given order: `lib/rack/test/methods.rb#L30` `lib/rack/mock_session.rb#L7` `lib/rack/test.rb#L244` `lib/rack/mock_session.rb#L30`. Notice how the `Rack::MockSession` is instantiated, how it is used when processing requests (e.g. when you call `get` method in your tests) and finally how the `call` method on your app is executed.

I hope that now it's clear why the test should look more like this (yes, you don't need to have a server running when executing your tests):

```
describe App do
  def app
    App.new
  end

  it "does a triple backflip" do
    get "/"
    expect(last_response.body).to eq("Hello, World")
  end
end
```

P.S.
Sorry for the form of links to `rack-test`, can't add more than 2 with my current points :P

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I thought it was useless until I refactored my whole project, and now this was my go to reference to figure it out. I see that you're fairly new to Stack Overflow so welcome! Keep writing great answers!

Comment: You're welcome! And I've been around for quite a while, just not writing answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be the class name, for example instead of:

```
def app
  MainAppLogic.new
end
```

You have to use

```
def app
  MainAppLogic
end
```

You shouldn't need to indicate the port for doing the `get`, because the rack app runs in the context of the tests; so this should be right way:

```
it "starts a server when initialized" do
    get "/"
    last_response.body.should be != nil
end
```

Also, as a recommendation prefer to use the new `expect` format instead of the `should`, see http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/

And your `MainAppLogic`, should be something like:

```
class MainAppLogic < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'Hello world'
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not using sinatra, so the last bit is irrelevant. I'll clarify that in my question

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't actually work for me. rspec still complains the same as before.

Comment: Even if you don't use Sinatra, you would still need to return the class name, not the instance of that class